# Finder jumping to currently selected item

Tags: macos, mac, finder

When I am browsing a long list of items, and have one of the items selected (whether above or below the current viewing area/viewport), quite often it jumps up or down to show the currently selected item - which is super annoying. I have unchecked Spring Loaded files and folder in preferences but with no avail. Is there any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: So true! When moving files around, the active window switches too quickly to properly allow me to place files in the folder I'm aiming for. Not only is the action hyper active at switching my active window prematurely- but it is hyper at moving windows which are close to the sides of the desktop, or partially outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply press "esc" to de-select an entry and you'll be able to scroll to your heart's content without the annoyance of jumping back to a selection.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about Column view? If so, then this isn't a bug, it's a feature... This behavior of Finder was already in Snow Leopard (and possibly previous versions as well):

Whenever you select another child folder in a column, the column left to it scrolls up or down just enough rows to show the current selected folder's parent. It does make sense, imho, and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this feature? In the situations that I use column view (all the time in deeply nested folder setups), and I am scrolling down and it keeps jumping me back up, it can be quite frustrating. Thank you!