# Finder always jumps to top of window in list view

Tags: macos, finder

When I expand or collapse directories in list view in a Finder window (every time i click on the expansion triangle), the window jumps to the top (with nothing selected).

I found this article: [Finder jumping to currently selected item](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45998/finder-jumping-to-currently-selected-item), and after pushing escape (the solution to *that* issue), my window jumps to the top of the window, instead of to the currently selected item.

Also tried the solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2577564?start=0&tstart=0 (unchecking 'spring loaded folders'), but the problem still persists.

Tried sorting by name/kind/date/size (only columns I have visible), problem still persists.

What can I do to fix this?

*Running:
OSX version 10.8.2
everything is up to date except a Java update that came out today March 13, 2013.*

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that there has been some corruption to that folder's `.DS_Store` file, which the Finder uses to remember it displayed that folder last time.

You'll probably want to check out [Consequences of deleting .DS_Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/consequences-of-deleting-ds-store) before you actually delete it so you know what to expect.

1. Make sure the Finder doesn't have the relevant folder open.
2. Open `Terminal.app` in `/Applications/Utilities`.
3. Type `cd` followed by a space.
4. Drag the icon for the folder with the issues into the Terminal to automatically fill in the full path to that folder, and press enter.
5. Enter `rm .DS_Store`.
6. You *might* need to `Relaunch` the Finder.

Comment: Hi Lake, thanks for responding. In the month since I posted this problem, my computer has stopped behaving strangely vis-a-vis this question. Perhaps due to an update or multiple restarts. If someone else is still seeing this issue and Lake's solution works, please let me know and I'll mark it as 'Answered'.